# Adding an unescaped query parameter in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, escaping, uri

I am trying to add an unescaped parameter to a URL with the help of UriBuilder. How can I prevent the characters of the parameter to be escaped?

```
query.Set("oauth_signature", CONSUMER_SECRET + "%26");
builder.Query = query.ToString();
```

The resulting URL always contains % as an escaped sequence as the oauth_signature value (which is %25 apparently).

Comment: Of what type is the 'query' variable in your code snippet?

Comment: It seems to be a subclass NameValueCollection (toString() produces a correct query string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%26 is & right?  Why not just do

```
query.Set("oaut_signature", CONSUMER_SECRET + "&");
```

Comment: Oh, well, I've previously used a simple string containing the query parameters to create a URI object and & was not being escaped; I thought I tried it using UriBuilder as well. Apparently I didn't, and your solution works as it should. Thank you very much! Sometimes one does not see the forest for the trees ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A dirty workaround would be to use a token to identify where the parameter should go in, and `string.Replace` it afterwards.  It's not safe though, which is probably why there's no easy way with `UriBuilder`.